# Should the article be "a" or "the"?

Tags: articles

Here is a text that I came across in "English in Use Supplementary Exercises":

That flat has a large sitting-room with views over the valley of Wharfedale. In the bedroom there are twin beds, a large cupboard and an armchair. The bathroom is next to the bedroom. There is a shower over the bath. The kitchen is modern. In the middle of the room is the round table. ***Outside, there is a small patio*** with some garden chairs and a fully-equipped barbecue. At the east end of the road (about 0.5km away), there are some shops which sell an amazing range of fresh local produce.

The confusing excerpt of the text is the one with the patio. In the answer sheet it says it should be "a", however, shouldn't it be "the" since it is a very specific part of a household like bathroom and bedroom? Moreover, there is a single patio.

Comment: "A/an" always means there's one, so that's no reason to use "the". In this example, there's "**a** large sitting-room", "**a** large cupboard and **an** armchair", and so on. What do you think is special about a small patio that it should use "the"?

Comment: The existence of a bedroom, bathroom and kitchen is taken for granted, but not all dwellings possess a patio.

Comment: I'm more confused by the use of "the" in "the round table". Certainly not all kitchens necessarily contain a table! Surely this should be "a round table" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the patio is quite specific, but you use **the** only when both speaker/writer and listener/reader know, or can reasonably guess, which one you are talking about. For example, if you are at a restaurant, you might say:

> Let's have lunch on **the** patio.

What makes this sentence different is that, when we use the expression **there is** to introduce the existence of something, the listener/reader doesn't yet know about the patio (that's why we are introducing it), so we use the indefinite article for singular items.

> Outside, there is **a** small patio.

Similarly, you say

> In the bedroom, there are twin beds, **a** large cupboard and **an** armchair.

You can find a more detailed explanation of this in section 50.2.c of the Oxford Guide to English Grammar by John Eastwood.